# How can I automate the "Click this URL to provide authorization" part of JIRA oauth?

Tags: python, oauth, jira, python-jira

I have the Oauth flow setup, and it works just fine, but my issue is this part:

```
STEP2: AUTHORIZATION
  Visit to the following URL to provide authorization:
  https://jira.me.com/plugins/servlet/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=c6shAreuL
```

Before continuing in the Oauth flow, I have to click the link, then click an `Accept` button to allow access. If my application restarts for some reason, I need a way to automate this step - how can I do that?

One of the primary issues I'm experiencing is that when this is launched via an entrypoint script in docker, it doesn't pause for the link to be clicked, and just failed out.

Comment: This is the main reason why OAuth exists. To prevent you from doing that..

Comment: Huh. I thought the main reason was so that you didn't have to store your credentials in your application, and could rely on a local openssl key.